# jQuery.closest(); traversing down the DOM not up

Tags: javascript, jquery

Afternoon peoples.

I am having a bit of a nightmare traversing a DOM tree properly. I have the following markup

```
http://pastie.org/999519
```

...
And I am trying to traverse from input.save at the bottom right the way up to div.node... This all works well with one copy of the markup but if I duplicate it (obvisouly changing the ID of the uppermost div.node and use jQuery.closest('div.node') for the upper of the div.node's it will return the element below it not the element above it (which is the right one). I've tried using parents() but that also has it's caveats. Is there some kind of contexyt that can be attached to closest to make it go up and not down? or is there a better way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Alex

P.S It seems that stackoverflow has done something weird to the markup! - I just triple checked it and it is fine but for some reason it's concate'd it below

Comment: I don't understand; `.closest()` *only* goes "up" the DOM.

Comment: He means up as in previous - ya need to get that code fixed so we can see where the hell input.save is at :) try pasting into notepad then into the SO editor, then make it code using the code button..

Comment: your html is invalid as it is missing a closing </div> tag

Comment: @Alex you have to make sure your code is indented with spaces, not tabs, when you paste it here

Comment: @pointy...I cleaned it up a little

Comment: Sorry guys...

I put it in a pastie because it would not go back into there.

http://pastie.org/999519

Comment: Please accept an answer that you feel has helped you the most. You should do this because it provides valuable feedback to the answerers. You can do this by clicking the check mark next to the answer you found most helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you really should use an id for the .save element, unless you have more, and if so then use a node prefix if you can, so `$('input.save')`...

I'm not sure what the problem is with your code. You say it is traversing down when you want it to go up? It is supposed to go up.

From jQuery docs at http://api.jquery.com/closest/:

> Get the first ancestor element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing ***up*** through the DOM tree

Maybe there is some problem with using `.find()` right after `closest()`. However, I don't think that would be a problem.

Comment: if you read the docs at jQuery they state it goes down not up (in the comments)...

I assumed it would go up aswel but it doesnt!.

I know about adding input.save etc etc.. this is just POC for something